# How to change the Drupal Commerce Stock formatter?

Tags: commerce

Drupal Commerce Stock displays the correct number of stock. For example:

Product Name, Price: $ 1.00, Stock: 20.

I would like to change the stock levels to 1, 2, 3, 4 and 4+. So if the stock level is 5 or more, the displayed stock will be 4+. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the stock of a product with 4+ when it's >5, assuming that you've got stock a field attached to the product and exposed to the node display (default behavior) you can use [hook_entity_view_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_alter/7) or [hook_node_view_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7) to alter the #markup of $build['product:field_stock']